# Recovering of Parity 1.7.8 wallet - integrating to Open Ethereum

Tags: keystore, wallet-transfer, parity-wallet, openethereum

I last used Parity in 2018 - having a wallet with different coins.
As I did a Windows Inplace-Upgrade I saved my C: drive and hoped at that time, that this should be enough to backup my account and wallet.

Since the reignited hype around crypto currency, I tried to access my wallet again with the old 1.7.8 client, but saw that Parity is outdated and was replaced with Open Ethereum. My client won't even start and downloading the blockchain does also not work, so I tried Open Ethereum. It seems that there is no GUI in the browser and everything is done with a CLI, so I'm a little bit confused how to restore or see my wallet.

What I have:

Parity Recovery Phrase for my account (account=wallet?)

Data from old_C:%appdata%\roaming\parity\ethereum\ (dapps, keys, network, signer)

How can I integrate the given data to the new Open Ethereum Client and have an insight to my wallet? If not possible with the Open Ethereum client - do I have other possibilities for extracting my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in pretty much the same situation, except that I used an even older version of Parity (circa 2017) originally.

### Easiest, not very secure

The easiest solution for me was to use [MEW (myEtherWallet)](https://www.myetherwallet.com) in online mode.
This is not the safest option as you're giving access to your private key, but was good enough for me because my wallet had ~$10.

1. Go to https://www.myetherwallet.com
2. Select Access My Wallet
3. Select "Software (keystore file, private key, mnemonic phrase)"
4. Select "Keystore File" and hit Continue
5. This would popup a file selection dialog.
   Go to `%AppData%\Parity\Ethereum\keys\ethereum` and select a keystore file without extension (it's a JSON file actually).
   In my case it was named like `UTC--2017-01-01T01-01-01Z--abcdefga-1234-1234-1234-abcdefaaaaaa`.
6. Enter password for the key and hit "Access Wallet".
7. It may take a while to import the key and show your wallet balance, but after that it allows to send/receive transfers.

### More secure

A more secure way is to use MEW Offline mode, which I didn't try myself.
Refer to https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/offline/using-mew-offline/ , which walks through steps to setup and use it.

The idea is basically to store private keys "offline" (even on a separate always offline computer) but submit signed transactions through online version of MEW.

### Using OpenEthereum

Yet another solution that should work based on my understanding is as follows.
It uses OpenEthereum, but the downside that it also relies on quite a bit of abandoned software.
As far as I understand OpenEthereum (Parity at that time) [lost its UI in version 2.0](https://www.parity.io/parity-ethereum-2-0/), so a separate project is needed to make use of JSON-RPC exported by OpenEthereum.

1. Copy "old_C:%appdata%\roaming\parity" to `AppData\Roaming` for your current user
2. Get latest OpenEthereum ([3.2.1](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum/releases/tag/v3.2.1) as of now)
3. Unzip it
4. Open `%AppData%\Parity\Ethereum\config.toml` in an editor and comment out "no_download" line if there's one
5. Run `openethereum db kill`, so that it discards the old DB (it won't discard your keys, but make a backup anyway) which is not compatible with new version
6. Run `openethereum account list` to make sure it sees your old Parity accounts
7. Run `openethereum` to sync to the network.
   If I understand correctly, this is going to take ~100GiB of disk space and more than a day to complete.
   (this is where I gave up)
8. Download and install Parity UI ([0.3.4](https://github.com/parity-js/shell/releases/tag/v0.3.4) as of now). It is abandoned since mid-2018, but seems to work with OpenEthereum 3.2.1. It shows UI similar to Parity 1.7.8.
9. An alternative (also abandoned since 2020) is Parity Fether ([0.4.3 beta](https://github.com/openethereum/fether/releases/tag/v0.4.3-beta) as of now). It provides a very minimalistic UI.